# How to rotate visible iOS keyboard with no UIViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, keyboard, orientation

I have a UIWindow with a hard-coded UIView inside. I'd prefer to keep it that way, is there a nice way to rotate an already visible keyboard? [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6432292/how-can-i-manually-rotate-the-keyboard-with-animation) asks the same thing, so I guess I'm really asking if the API used by UIViewController to rotate the keyboard is private API. I'm not going to use it if it is, but I'd still be interested in what it is. And how you found out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIViewController handles the rotation for your, you really should use one. Don't try to reinvent the wheel, stick to the best practices and you will avoid a lot of unnecessary work.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AppArchitecture/AppArchitecture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH3-SW18

> The UIViewController class is the base class for all view controller
>   objects. It provides default functionality for loading views,
>   presenting them, rotating them in response to device rotations, and
>   several other standard system behaviors